# read .csv file with Names and Labels into R

Tags: r, label, read.table, hmisc

I have a .csv file that I need to read into R. The first row contains the names (e.g. BFI1, BFI2, CAQ2) and the the second row contains the question which I would also like to access in R (e.g. "I enjoy going to parties"). Each row after the first two corresponds to one participant.

I would like to be able to access the Codes and the text in R. (e.g. to use `grep` to access all the questions from one survey, and also to see the item text if needed. I need the numerical responses to be numeric.

```
BFI1, BFI2, CAQ1, CAQ2
Likes to read, Enjoys Parties, Is Nervous, Loves Books
3, 7, 1, 4
4, 5, 3, 3
```

I want to read this in so that I can access either the names (row 1) or the text (as labels maybe). I have looked at the `Hmisc` package but their label functionality seems limited.

Is there any way to read in this .csv file and access both of these values?

Comment: Agree w/ step 1 but for step 2 should a skip argument so the numeric values can get detected properly.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're okay with having the labels as a separate vector, but here's an idea.  Suppose your file name is `x.txt`

```
## set up an argument list for scan() - just to avoid repetition
scanArgs <- list(
    file = "x.txt", what = "", nlines = 1, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE
)

## read the data with no header and add the first line as names
df <- setNames(
    read.table("x.txt", skip = 2, sep = ","), 
    do.call(scan, scanArgs)
)
#   BFI1 BFI2 CAQ1 CAQ2
# 1    3    7    1    4
# 2    4    5    3    3

## make the label vector
labels <- setNames(do.call(scan, c(scanArgs, skip = 1)), names(df))
#            BFI1             BFI2             CAQ1             CAQ2 
# "Likes to read" "Enjoys Parties"     "Is Nervous"    "Loves Books"
```

So the elements in `labels` correspond to the columns in `df` and the columns are numeric.

Note that `x.txt` was created with

```
txt <- 'BFI1, BFI2, CAQ1, CAQ2
Likes to read, Enjoys Parties, Is Nervous, Loves Books
3,7,1,4
4,5,3,3'
writeLines(txt, "x.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Michelle Usuelli's answer and with Rich Scriven correction, you can write this function:

```
read_csv_with_labels <- function(fileName)
{
 library(Hmisc)

 # read the first two lines
 varNames <- read.csv(fileName, nrows = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE)
 varLabels <- read.csv(fileName, nrows = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

 # read the data
 df <- read.csv(fileName, skip = 2)

 # assign variable names and labels to the dataframe
 names(df) <- varNames
 label(df) <- varLabels 

 return(df)
}
```

I think this should be included in the basic functionality of read.csv and read_csv.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nrows and skip arguments or read.csv

```
nameFile <- "data.csv"

# read the first two lines
vectorNames <- read.csv(nameFile, nrows = 1)
vectorDescription <- read.csv(nameFile, nrows = 1, skip = 1)

# read the data
dfIn <- read.csv(nameFile, skip = 2)
names(dfIn) <- vectorNames
```

Comment: I think you need `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `vectorNames`.  Otherwise they will be coerced to their integer values when you assign them as names

Answer (score 0):

@Richard Scriven I used your code and followed it up with this using the package

```
library(Hmisc)
y=data.frame(temp=rep(NA,nrow(df)))  
for (i in 1:length(labels)){  
x=df[,i]  
label(x)=labels[i]   
y[names(df)[i]]=x  
}  
y$temp=NULL  
y  
#  BFI1 BFI2 CAQ1 CAQ2
# 1    3    7    1    4
# 2    4    5    3    3
label(y)
#            BFI1             BFI2             CAQ1             CAQ2 
# "Likes to read" "Enjoys Parties"     "Is Nervous"    "Loves Books"
```